# Dependency Injection Quartz.Net Scheduler

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, quartz.net

I'm currently trying to use a repository to update some data in the DB using quartz.net.
Keep in mind that I'm using ASP.Net Core 3.1

The problem that I'm currently having is that when I'm injecting my IUserProjectRepository in the constructor of the IJob the job wont get executed and I also get an error in the Quartz DB implementation:

[image]

So, this is how my `startup.cs` looks like:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddTransient<UserProjectStatusJob>();
      services.AddTransient(provider => GetScheduler().Result);
    }
....
    private async Task<IScheduler> GetScheduler()
    {
      NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection
      {
        { "quartz.scheduler.instanceName", "Cliche" },
        { "quartz.scheduler.instanceId", "Cliche" },
        { "quartz.jobStore.type", "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" },
        { "quartz.jobStore.useProperties", "true" },
        { "quartz.jobStore.dataSource", "default" },
        { "quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix", "QRTZ_" },
        {
          "quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString",
          "connectionstring"
        },
        { "quartz.dataSource.default.provider", "SqlServer" },
        { "quartz.threadPool.threadCount", "1" },
        { "quartz.serializer.type", "json" },
      };
      
      
      var schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
      var scheduler = await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
      await scheduler.Start();
      return scheduler;
    }
```

This is how my Job (`UserProjectStatusJob`) Looks like:

```
  public class UserProjectStatusJob : IJob
  {

    private IUserProjectRepository _userProjectRepository;
    public UserProjectStatusJob(IUserProjectRepository userProjectRepository)
    {
      this._userProjectRepository = userProjectRepository;
    }

    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
      try
      {
        JobDataMap dataMap = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;
        string userProjectId = dataMap.GetString("userProjectId");
        string userProjectProjectId = dataMap.GetString("userProjectProjectId");
        _userProjectRepository.CloseUserProject(userProjectProjectId, userProjectId);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
      }


      return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
  }
```

I create my job in the same `UserProjectRepository`:

```
 public class UserProjectRepository : IUserProjectRepository
  {
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly IFileService _fileService;
    private readonly INotificationRepository _notificationRepository;
    private readonly IScheduler _scheduler;

    public UserProjectRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext,
      IFileService fileService,
      INotificationRepository notificationRepository,
      IScheduler scheduler)
    {
      this._scheduler = scheduler;
      this._notificationRepository = notificationRepository;
      this._fileService = fileService;
      this._dbContext = dbContext;
    }


    public async Task CreateCronJobForUserProject(UserProject userProject)
    {
// Add Later in to startAt
      TimeSpan timeToTrigger = userProject.Project.Assignment.DeadLine - DateTime.Now;
      ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity($"Check Availability-{DateTime.Now}")
        .StartAt(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(15))
        .WithPriority(1)
        .Build();

      IDictionary<string, object> map = new Dictionary<string, object>()
      {
        {"userProjectId", $"{userProject.Id}" },
        {"userProjectProjectId", $"{userProject.ProjectId}" },
      };
      
      IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<UserProjectStatusJob>()
        .WithIdentity($"Check Availability-{DateTime.Now}")
        .SetJobData(new JobDataMap(map))
        .Build();
      

        await this._scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

    }
}
```

EDIT:

Error:
After taking a closer look I did found this:

```
[14:46:50 ERR] An error occurred instantiating job to be executed. job= 'DEFAULT.Check Availability-10/28/2020 14:46:35'
Quartz.SchedulerException: Problem instantiating class 'IKL.Data.Services.UserProjectStatusJob: Cannot instantiate type which has no empty constructor (Parameter 'UserProjectStatusJob')'
 ---> System.ArgumentException: Cannot instantiate type which has no empty constructor (Parameter 'UserProjectStatusJob')
```

Comment: Do you get any exception? If so, please post the exception details.

Comment: No, unfortunately there is no error, the job isn't executed and as you can see in the screenshot the trigger state is then set to error.

Comment: I edited my post, I did found an error after all.

Comment: I found a solution, I used Hangfire instead of Quartz...

Comment: One option would have been to use the official integration packages to get the injection working https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/microsoft-di-integration.htm and  https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/hosted-services-integration.html

Comment: @WilsonSilva how did you solve it with hangfire? I am trying quartz as hangfire has similar issue with dependency injection, could you please share an example on recurring jobs using hangfire? using a class that has dependencies on its constructor... Thanks in advance